# How to avoid routerLink modify the HTML <a> tag?

Tags: angular

I want to use a bootstrap free theme in my angular application. But the problem is that when I add routerLink to my <a tag, angular automatically close the tag  even if there are some HTML code in between <a and

```
    <a class="nav-link" href="/client-list" routerLink = "/client-list">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
    <span>Type de client</span></a>
```

becomes

```
    <a _ngcontent-omu-c100="" href="/client-list" routerlink="/client-list" class="nav-link"></a>
```

For me it is catastrophic as I can't use any bootstrap theme :(

Any work around ?

Comment: in fact, It must work, there must be something else preventing... However can you try removing the href attribute and just keep the routerLink and check.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue because my path has a "/" at the beginning. In the search console I got the message :

Error: NG04014: Invalid configuration of route '/chart': path cannot start with a slash

After removing the / from the path, the <a tag was displayed correctly.